# How to filter the values in jtable using Regular expressions in java?

Tags: swing, jtable

I have a jtable as given below

**name age**

```
arun  25
john  30
anuk  45
caml  30
raju  32
avan  70
```

I want to filter the rows only where name starts 'a' using regular expressions or else.?..
    How to filter....Can u anyone help me?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I tried Rowfilter..But its not working

Comment: RowFilter is the way to go ... the problem is in the code that you are not showing, time for an SSCCE

Answer (score 0):

JIDE Grids has a whole set of features on the Swing table. It's FitlerableTableModel can take a RegexFilter which can be a regular expression.

Comment: wouldn't go commercial (especially not when it is doing the filtering/sorting in a not standard way) when core already supports it... The OP isn't asking for any bells nor whistles, just simple applying the standard api, which has a regexFilter ;-)